# Getting Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default for the "keyword" field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting 
**Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default** for the field os the type "keyword".

Is this an expected behaviour?

The problem that I cannot fix the issue with the recommended approach (**Set fielddata=true**), since it throws:
Mapping definition for [xxx] has unsupported parameters:  [fielddata : true]

Comment: can you add your mapping and query

Comment: `"upper_level_property": {
          "properties": {
            "failing_property": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
 }`


`"query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": { "match_all": {} },
        "filter": { "match" : { "some_property": "valX" } }
      }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
      "field_missing": {
        "missing": {
          "field": "failing_property"
        }
      }
    }`

Comment: I am not sure how to keep formatting.

Comment: Can you check GET <index name>/_mapping api.  Property upper_level_property is of type object . It will create a field upper_level_property.failing_property. You might be inserting data as failing_property instead of upper_level_property.failing_property which will create a different field with type text

Comment: But I am not inserting here. I am just querying data

Comment: Field data error will not come when type is keyword. Can you paste result of GET <index>/_mapping here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the elasicsearch documentation, this is the default for performance reasons.

> Fielddata can consume a lot of heap space, especially when loading
>   high cardinality text fields.

You can enable it like this:

```
PUT my_index/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "my_field": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html

Comment: As I'd mentioned in the title:
I am getting Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default for the field of the type "keyword". The type is "keyword" not "text". And no, it cannot have a "fielddata" option